# Passing xml vallues from windows events as a variables

Tags: windows, powershell, event-viewer

I appreciate any advice from Powershell wizards out there.

I am trying to setup an email alert that will be triggered on event but having problems passing values as a variable so I can use it later in the body and subject of an email.

I have a few lines of script that pulls an event and stores it as XML but have no luck converting the value to variable to call it later.

```
$event = wevtutil qe 'Microsoft-Windows-Base-Filtering-Engine-Connections/Operational' /rd:true /c:1 /q:"*[System[(EventID=2000)]]" /f:renderedxml
$xmlresults = [xml]$event
$eventDate = $xmlresults.event.system.timecreated.systemtime
$eventTime = get-date $eventDate -Format ('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

Now when calling `$xmlresults.event.eventdata.data` I can see all values in a table:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $xmlresults.Event.EventData.Data

Name                                                                                                                          #text                                                                                                                       
----                                                                                                                          -----                                                                                                                       
ConnectionId                                                                                                                  1324000000003942                                                                                                        
MachineAuthenticationMethod                                                                                                   2                                                                                                                           
RemoteMachineAccount                                                                                                          DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$                                                                                                         
UserAuthenticationMethod                                                                                                      2                                                                                                                           
RemoteUserAcount                                                                                                              DOMAIN\USERNAME$                                                                                                         
RemoteIPAddress                                                                                                               XXXX:XXXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXXX:XXX:XXXX                                                                                       
LocalIPAddress                                                                                                                XXXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::1                                                                                                       
TechnologyProviderKey                                                                                                         {XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX}                                                                                      
IPsecTrafficMode                                                                                                              1                                                                                                                           
DHGroup                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                           
StartTime                                                                                                                     2021-05-17T13:52:38.103Z
```

How do I store the values of `RemoteMachineAccount` and `RemoteUserAccount` as a variable so I can call upon it later in the script when composing email alert and log input by simply using something along the lines of `$computer` and `$user`?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$xmlresults.Event.EventData.Data.Where({$_.Name -eq 'RemoveMachineAccount'}).InnerText` should do the trick

Comment: Splendid sir, that is exacltly what I was looking for. many thanks Mathias.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a few specifically named properties, you can use the `.Where({})` method to filter the nodes returned by the XML provider and grab the text from that specific property:

```
$RemoteMachineAccount = $xmlresults.Event.EventData.Data.Where({$_.Name -eq 'RemoteMachineAccount'}).InnerText
$RemoteUserAccount    = $xmlresults.Event.EventData.Data.Where({$_.Name -eq 'RemoteUserAccount'}).InnerText
```

If you need to discover/use them dynamically, another option is to convert the node list into a hashtable:

```
$eventData = @{}
$xmlresults.Event.EventData.Data.ForEach({ $eventData[$_.Name] = $_.InnerText })
```

At which point you can dereference the individual property values by name:

```
$eventData["RemoteUserAccount"]
```